# Querying a Nested Document using an array - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Document like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61e10561a06dd136bc848b1f"),
"packagingCharges" : {
    "small" : 0,
    "medium" : 0,
    "large" : 0
},
"themeColor" : "#168EBA",
"openingTime" : "9 am",
"closingTime" : "9 pm",
"discount" : "0",
"isRestaurantActive" : true,
"restaurantName" : "Aman Restaurant",
"address" : "Faridabad",
"createdBy" : ObjectId("61dd2182871d7c2be8b41006"),
"restaurantTokenImage" : "..\\tmp\\uploads\\RestaurantImages\\1642136929834_999192.jpg",
"restaurantLogoImage" : "..\\tmp\\uploads\\RestaurantImages\\1642136929928_doreMON.JPG",
"coins" : 0,
"isGstRegistered" : true,
"offers" : [ 
    {
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c221"),
        "giftItem" : "Pizza",
        "coins" : 10,
        "menuId" : ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c220")
    }
],
"menu" : [ 
    {
        "menuItem" : "chapati",
        "price" : 5,
        "menuItemImageName" : "979696859_054.jpg",
        "menuItemImage" : "..\\tmp\\uploads\\menuItemImages\\1642136982717_979696859_054.jpg",
        "isGift" : false,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "excludeMe" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("61e10596a06dd136bc848b20"),
        "coins" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "menuItem" : "Pizza",
        "price" : 50,
        "menuItemImageName" : "979696859_054.jpg",
        "menuItemImage" : "..\\tmp\\uploads\\menuItemImages\\1642137069230_979696859_054.jpg",
        "isGift" : true,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "excludeMe" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c220"),
        "coins" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "menuItem" : "Pasta",
        "price" : 80,
        "menuItemImageName" : "979696859_054.jpg",
        "menuItemImage" : "..\\tmp\\uploads\\menuItemImages\\1642137188767_979696859_054.jpg",
        "isGift" : false,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "excludeMe" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("61e10664202546421025c222"),
        "coins" : 10
    }
],
"createdAt" : ISODate("2022-01-14T05:08:50.032Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-01-14T05:13:08.879Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

}

I want to find out menus with help of an array [ObjectId("61e10596a06dd136bc848b20"), ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c220")] and I don't want rest of the fields. What's the best query I can write. I am using mongo as database and javascript or Node for backend

Comment: Don't get offended but you're looking for other people to do the thinking and coding for you, most people here want to see your code sample to show that you have put some effort in trying to get your code to work... Please attach your code in the editing box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` find `document`
- `$project` keep only `menu`
- `$unwind` separate `menu` array
- `$match` find id `_in` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "menu._id": {
        "$in": [
          ObjectId("61e10596a06dd136bc848b20"),
          ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c220")
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "menu": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$menu"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "menu._id": {
        "$in": [
          ObjectId("61e10596a06dd136bc848b20"),
          ObjectId("61e105ed202546421025c220")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cN3IYyuBVmi)